# Group an array with same value in actionscript

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have an array:

```
var exArr:Array = [5,6,10,6,5,11,7,9,12,8,8,13,7,9,14];
```

I want to array:

```
var resultArr:Array = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may use full to you.

```
var a:Array = [5,6,10,6,5,11,7,9,12,8,8,13,7,9,14];
a.sort();
var i:int = 0;
while(i < a.length) {
    while(i < a.length+1 && a[i] == a[i+1]) {
        a.splice(i, 1);
    }
    i++;
}
```

for other, [see here](http://englishblog.flepstudio.org/tutorials/removing-duplicate-elements-of-array-with-actionscript-3/)

Comment: This gives the result `10,11,12,13,14,5,6,7,8,9`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var exArr:Array = [5,6,10,6,5,11,7,9,12,8,8,13,7,9,14];

function group(subject:Array):Array
{
    var base:Array = subject.slice().sort(Array.NUMERIC);
    var prev:Number = base[0];

    for(var i:int = 1; i < base.length; i++)
    {
        if(base[i] === prev)
        {
            base.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }

        prev = base[i];
    }


    return base;
}



trace( group(exArr) );
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer - single loop over nested loop